# Can change id to custom_id when insert data from a table to another?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to insert data from a table to another but I want, when I transfer this data to other table ids to change. For example(Table1 ID=1001 -> Table2 custom_id=custom_1001). I'm trying to do it in Laravel.

This is how I transfer data from table1 to table2. But I don't now how to add 'custom_' before id on table2

```
$qry = DB::table('table1')->get();


foreach($qry as $key => $data_in) {
    DB::table('table2')->insert([
        "custom_id" => $data_in->id, 
        "status" => $data_in->status
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `"custom_id" => 'custom_' . $data_in->id`

Comment: Here @Maksim gave you a perfect example how you could achieve that

Comment: @Maksim This shou me an error : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'custom_1001' for column 'custom_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `table2` (`custom_id`, `status`) values (custom_1001, Y))

Comment: Than you must change column type to string in migration. Please study the basics..

Answer (score 1):

first make `custom_id` string then just do something like this:

```
$qry = DB::table('table1')->get();


foreach($qry as $key => $data_in) {
    DB::table('table2')->insert([
        "custom_id" => "custom_" . $data_in->id, 
        "status" => $data_in->status
    ]);
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. But what if i need to keep custom_id as primary key and int?

Comment: if you add string into the value you cannot set the column as int

Comment: Understand. Thank you @ManojKiranAppathurai

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to add prefix

```
$qry = DB::table('table1')
->selectRaw('CONCAT("custom_",id) AS custom_id')
->addSelect('status')
->get();
    
    foreach($qry as $key => $data_in) {
            DB::table('table2')->insert((array)$data_in);
    }
```

Comment: This give me same error : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'custom_1001' for column 'custom_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into table2 (custom_id, status) values (custom_1001, Y))

Comment: can you share the migration file for ```table2```